# What would be the drawbacks of using Saxon API in LHS of rules in Drools

Tags: drools, saxon

I'm working on a project which recieves XML chunks as input and produce some simple POJOs as result. The application should be able to configured/programmed to be able to parse different kind of XML chunks! I'm planing to use Drools to make the logic dynamic and programmable, but it'll endup using Saxon XPath Api in LHS of rules in Drools' Rules (e.g. using `eval`).
I'm curious to know what is the drawbacks?

P.S. I found this [Evaluating XPath expressions in JBoss Drools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698790/evaluating-xpath-expressions-in-jboss-drools) topic, they don't mention drawbacks and alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Drools, but I would think that the main thing to watch out for is that you are not parsing and compiling each XPath expression (and perhaps even reinitialising Saxon!) every time an XPath expression is executed.